# What is the difference between passive master and slave in mysql replication?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

There are several ways to configure mysql replication. I know how to configure the replication cluster to use master-master-active-passive model or master-slave model.

If I configure passive master and slave to be "read-only" in each model and both passive master and slave can be promoted to be active master in failover, then I'm wondering what is the difference between them?